# Can 2 different GPU on same mother perform gaming and streaming

Tags: windows-10, video-streaming

I was jus browsing around internet to find if I can run 2 different GPU in same PC I found the answer for it. But did not get my doubts cleared completely that if could game on my main GPU on the moniter connected to it and let the 2nd GPU handel my obs and chat section. So is this possible to do or should I have a completely second pc go to do so.

Answer (score 2):

In order to record video for streaming the framebuffer would have to be copied from the graphics card that is playing the game to the other graphics device, for that device to then encode it. While possible it will require bandwidth and some delay in order to encode. These frames will be transferred completely uncompressed.

Most modern graphics cards also include dedicated video encoding blocks at their output. This dedicated block will not significantly affect the shaders that are producing the images you see. It may use some GPU memory bandwidth to encode and move the encoded video to the host, but unless your graphics card is *permanently* at 100% memory bandwidth used it is likely not a significant loss. The amount of memory (and PCIe) bandwidth used here is likely less than copying uncompressed frames across the PCIe bus to the other graphics device.

As such there may be slightly less delay in using the same graphics card for playing and recording video, along with less PCIe bandwidth used meaning that texture data and control of the graphics card is possibly slightly faster. Controlling two independent devices might also incur more CPU overhead.

It depends where your bottleneck in encoding video for streaming is. I would expect it to be far more efficient for one device to produce the video and directly encode its output.

Otherwise a second computer recording the output and doing the streaming may well be more efficient than doing it using a second device in the first machine.

Comment: Can I know what output I get with this spec while streaming on dual GPU. specs- CPU: AMD Ryzen 7 3700x, GPU 1:RTX 2070 SUPER 8GB , GPU 2:GTX 1050TI 4GB , RAM: 16*2 @ 3000mhz.